# Amazon SES not allowing diacritics characters in from field

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Using following `SendEmailRequest` containing characters with diacritics..

```
var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
{
    Source = "Kůň <kun@test.com>",  
    Destination = destination,
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = new Content(message.Subject),
        Body = mailBody
    }
};
```

..and dispatching it via Amazon SES results in sender being displayed incorrectly as **KoH** instead of **Kůň** in email client.

Is there a quick fix to get around this? How do I tell SES client to treat source as UTF-8? There is no such issue with subject.

Answer (score 0):

The source code encoding must be declared.
Follow the link for more details about unicode:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx